# Setting specfic margins for thesis in Latex

Tags: margins, geometry

I am required to have a full binding margin of 40 mm on the left side of odd pages and the right side of even pages - other margins must be 25mm minimum.
I have typed:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
  margin=25mm,
  bindingoffset=15mm,
  heightrounded,
}
```

however I assume there must be a margin offset? As the left hand margin on my odd numbered pages is 45mm and the other is 25mm, but on the even numbered pages the left hand margin is 30mm and the right side margin is 40mm, why aren't these the same?

Comment: This depends on the document class `twoside` option, as far as I know. Try `innermargin` and `outermargin` settings

Comment: Hi lmac, I think it would be helpful if you postet a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A MWE incuding the documentclass would also answer Cristian's question.

Comment: @Dave: I've made a suggestion and did not ask something ;-)

Comment: Is there any news here?